# how to remove a particular list using jquery?

Tags: jquery

When I attempt to remove a list using jquery remove() method, the list remains unmoved. 
Here's the code I'm using to remove the list:

```
              $("li.span.folder").remove();
```

Can someone tell what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank You...

Comment: How does the corresponding HTML element look like?

Comment: you have a `<li class="span folder>` tag?

Comment: OIC the problem, I have span as a class and not as an element

Comment: Thanks Chumkiu for steering my thoughts in the right direction of resolution. I changed it to $(li span.folder).remove() and it worked

Comment: `li` need to be removed itself not its content, if you want to remove element of list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
$("li span.folder").remove();
```

if your structure is like:

```
<ul>
    <li> <span class="folder"></span> </li>
</ul>
```

... just if you want to keep the `li` element removing the `<span>`.

---

**If you want to get rid of the `li` parent ...** than do:

```
$("span.folder").parent('li').remove();
```

Comment: OK, its like my solution and like what I think, you beat me :P

Comment: @Al-Mothafar GLad you like it :P

Comment: thanks for understanding my inexperience question and its working now

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you meant to do:

```
$("li .span .folder").remove();
```

instead of

```
$("li.span.folder").remove();
```

?

(Or some other combination, of where the dots and spaces should go?)

Post your HTML.